# Android convert byte to file

Tags: android, file, drive

With this code, I obtain the contents of a file located in the root of Google Drive. Now my requirement is to convert the array of byte [] into a file and save it in the external memory device. when debugging I get this error:

```
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at com.spjanson.gdaademo.MainActivity$4.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:276)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at com.spjanson.gdaademo.MainActivity$4.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:250)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENAMETOOLONG (File name too long)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
05-25 18:08:56.787 19204-20008/com.spjanson.gdaademo W/System.err:  ... 9 more
```

static method to get file from drive

```
static byte[] read(String id) {
    byte[] buf = null;
    if (mGAC != null && mGAC.isConnected() && id != null) try {
        DriveFile df = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGAC, DriveId.decodeFromString(id));
        DriveContentsResult rslt = df.open(mGAC, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();
        if ((rslt != null) && rslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            DriveContents cont = rslt.getDriveContents();
            buf = UT.is2Bytes(cont.getInputStream());
            cont.discard(mGAC);    // or cont.commit();  they are equiv if READONLY
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        UT.le(e);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

async to save file

```
@Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                mBusy = true;
                ArrayList<ContentValues> cvs = GDAA.searchDB(UT.FILE_NAME);
                if (cvs != null) for (ContentValues cv : cvs) {
                    String gdid = cv.getAsString(UT.GDID);
                    System.out.println("ID..... " + gdid);
                    byte[] buf = GDAA.read(gdid);

                    String str = null;
                    if (buf != null) {
                        try {
                            str = new String(buf, "UTF-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        FileChannel source = null;
                        FileChannel destination = null;
                        File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfile.db");
                        String backupDBPath = "myfile.db";
                        File internalDB = new File(str);
                        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
                        try {
                            source = new FileInputStream(internalDB).getChannel();
                            destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                            source.close();
                            destination.close();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                        //String str = buf == null ? "" : new String(buf);
                        //File fl = UT.str2File(str, "database.db");
                        }


                }

                return null;
            }
```

Comment: you want to save it as **yourFile.bin** ?

Comment: I want to save a file as database

Comment: You removd the error from your logcat. So we dont know the error.

Answer (score 1):

I would say problem is here:

```
File internalDB = new File(str);
```

The file name for `internalDB` is being set to the what you you are reading in from the buffer and it is throwing:

```
android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENAMETOOLONG (File name too long)
```

Comment: which way should I follow?

Comment: @user2847219 Did you mean to have 'str' as the file name?  From your code it looks like you might have meant to use 'sd' as the file name.  So File internalDB = new File(sd); instead of File internalDB = new File(str);